# Does Serilog package required in .Net core?

Tags: serilog

I have been using Serilog in classic .Net and its been working fine. Now I am using Serilog for .Net Core. Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging) I need to Install

```
 Install-Package Serilog.Extensions.Logging
 Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile
```

with this setup I was able to log to file.

However I dont see it is required to install main `Serilog` package

```
       Install-Package Serilog
```

With classic .Net this was mandatory package, Is `Serilog` package not required for .Net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Serilog` package is a dependency of the other two, so by installing either, the core Serilog package will be installed automatically.

Comment: that's not true with .net core. I don't see its been installed. My question is specific to .net core

Comment: Howdy! I believe you might be mistaken. .NET Core projects use project.json, which handles transitive dependencies much better than the old packages.config system. Finding the packages on disk however can be quite tricky under the new system, so that might be where the challenge lies. Either way, the setup you're using _definitely_ pulls in the Serilog package, the sink/config ones are very slim. HTH!

Comment: If `Serilog` package is dependency for `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` package then when I install `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` it should also automatically add `Serilog` as dependency  in project.json. Well its not adding `Serilog` as dependent package  and I am still able to log it successfully. So the question if I really need to `Serilog` package in .Net Core?

Comment: That's not the case - unlike packages.config, only the top-level dependencies of an application are listed in project.json. If you're using Visual Studio, you can expand the "Dependencies" node in the project tree to see the complete dependency graph for a project. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks..You are right. Its was hidden in the references, but not listed in project.json